# Button de site funciona no desktop, mas não em mobile

Tags: wordpress, mobile, button, lightbox

Tenho um botão no site que aciona um lightbox para preencher um formulario de contato.
O problema que o botão é clicável apenas em Desktop. Quando acesso por um dispositivo mobile, esse botão não funciona mais.

Esse é o código que eu estou usando:

```
[formlightbox_call title="lightbox_form" class="2"]<button style="background-color: #9c0f13; border-radius: 5px;">Contate-nos</button>
[/formlightbox_call][formlightbox_obj id="2" onload="false"][contact-form-7 id="13" title="Formulário de contato 1"][/formlightbox_obj]
```

O que estou fazendo errado?

Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver o problema.
Segue o código que utilizei.

```html
<h5 style="font-size: 18px; text-align: center;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" href="#"><span style="font-size: 9px;">[formlightbox_call title="" class="2"]</span><button style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: #9c0f13; text-align: center;" type="button">Consulte-nos!
[/formlightbox_call][formlightbox_obj id="2" style="padding: 9px;"][contact-form-7 id="13" title="Formulário de contato 1"][/formlightbox_obj]</button></a></h5>
```